# Compare varchar text with date format in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a small table with sample dates.

```
create table tblSample(checkDate varchar(20));

insert into tblSample values('10-Mar-19');
insert into tblSample values('11-Mar-19');
insert into tblSample values('12-Mar-19');
insert into tblSample values('13-Mar-19');
insert into tblSample values('14-Mar-19');

select * from tblSample;

select * from tblSample where checkDate=convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101);
```

In the above date was stored as a text.

Now I would like to compare with date field. (compare with current date)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a really simple solution:

```
alter table tblSample alter column checkDate date;
```

That is, don't store dates as strings in your data.  Fix the data model to use the correct format!

If you want to compare the value to the current date, you have to remember the timestamp.  You seem to note that the time component is an issue by converting `getdate()` to a string with no time, but it is in the wrong format.

Once you have a `date`, simply use `where checkDate = convert(date, getdate())`.

Comment: Bad requirement

Comment: It should store string also.

Comment: Also a bad requirement

Comment: Any possibility without changing type?

Comment: Not changing the datatype is just terrible. The correct datatype is paramount to a functioning system. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cast()` :

```
where cast(checkDate as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

However, the primary suggestion is to change the data model to store dates as standard date format.

Comment: insert into tblSample values('13-03-2019')

Comment: there is another record like this

Comment: @user2515629 And this is why you shouldn't store dates as strings. Now it is highly likely that you have garbage values that cannot be converted. And you will also have ambiguous values. Here we can assume that your example is March 13. But surely there will be others where you cannot know if the format is "mm-dd" or "dd-mm". Throw in 2 digit years and you suffer more. Embrace your doom or change your table.